# Must a binary relation on a set $X$ be defined for all elements in $X$?

Tags: relations, binary-operations

When defining a binary relation $R \subseteq X^2$, does there have to be a definite "true" or "false" value for a pair $(x,y) \in R$, or does it only have to be "true" to be included, and excluded otherwise?

For example, can I define the relation on $\mathbb{Z}$, $(x,y)\in R$ if and only if $x|y$? Even though $(0,y)$ is undefined for any value $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ (except $0$, depending on which text book you read..)

**EDIT:**

changed a typo from "$(x,0)$ is undefined..." to "$(0,y)$ is undefined..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either $x$ divides $y$, or it does not; whether $x\mid y$ (and hence whether $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$) is not undefined for any $x,y\in\Bbb Z$, though whether $\langle 0,0\rangle\in R$ may depend on your conventions. In particular, $\langle n,0\rangle\in R$ for every $n$ except possibly $0$, and $\langle 0,n\rangle\notin R$ for any $n$.

More generally, a binary relation $R$ on $X$ is simply a well-defined subset of $X\times X$. We may not always be able to tell whether some particular pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ is in $R$, but it either is or is not; there is no fuzzy in-between state. For instance, let

$$R=\{\langle n,d\rangle:\text{the }n\text{-th digit of the decimal expansion of }\pi\text{ is }d\}\;.$$

For sufficiently large values of $n$ we don’t know whether $\langle n,1\rangle\in R$, but we do know that this question has a definite answer.

(I suppose that I should mention that there actually is a notion of [fuzzy sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_set) with a corresponding notion of degree of membership, but I assume that we are talking here about the usual notion of binary relation.)

Comment: Yep, just the usual notion. So because $n|0$ is not defined for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $(n,0) \notin R$, because it definitely cannot be in $R$, it doesnt matter whether it can be computed or not? Is it considered sloppy to have cases like this? or is it perfectly fine?

Comment: If we use a less well-defined relation than $x|y$, say $(x,y)\in R$ iff $\frac{1}{x-y}$. Can we still apply this as a relation over $\mathbb{Z}$? or do we have to say $(x,y)\in R$ iff $\frac{1}{x-y} \land x \neq y$?

Comment: by "well-defined" above, I meant in the sense of "well-travelled", hehe

Comment: oops, also i just realised i made a typo and meant $(0,n) \notin R$.. sorry, have edited my question to avoid confusion to other people..

Comment: @guskenny83: No, $n\mid 0$ is **true** for every non-zero integer $n$, and $0\mid n$ is **false** for every non-zero integer $n$. Whether $0\mid 0$ is a matter of convention: some declare it true, and others declare it false. But whichever convention is used, there is no doubt about which pairs $\langle m,n\rangle$ are in the ‘divides’ relation. As for $\frac1{x-y}$, that isn’t a statement about anything, so it’s meaningless to say that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ iff $\frac1{x-y}$.

Comment: sorry, i got caught up trying to construct the example to be undefined for some value of $x$ and $y$, I forgot to make it a statement as well.. i meant to say $(x,y) \in R$ iff $\frac{1}{x-y} < \frac{1}{2}$ or something like that. Can we say that is a relation over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @guskenny83: Sure; you simply have then that for all integers $x$, $\langle x,x\rangle\notin R$. When $\frac1{x-y}$ is not defined, then it’s certainly not less than $\frac12$.

Comment: Okay, good, thanks for clarifying that. So then I suppose it is kind of analogous to the concept of semi-decidable in computability then? We are only interested in the positive outcomes and do not care about those that which cannot be computed?

Comment: @guskenny83: I would not have said that computation enters into it: you have a relation $R$ defined by $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ iff $\varphi(x,y)$, where $\varphi$ is some property that a given pair of objects either have or do not have (though in some cases we may not be able to determine which is actually the case). The only outcome of interest is whether $\varphi(x,y)$ is true for a particular pair $\langle x,y\rangle$. The closest that I can come to what you’re suggesting is that if the outcome is demonstrably not **true**, then it is necessarily **false**.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I was asking.. When defining a relation, if something is not demonstrably true then it is necessarily false. Thanks

Comment: @guskenny83: You’re welcome.